# Prove an inequality between expected values of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

For $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we define the function $f_a$ as:
$$f_a(x) = \begin{cases}
x - a; & \text{if } x \geq a \newline
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Let X and Y be random variables with integer values for which $E(|X|), E(|Y|) < \infty$. Let's assume that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the following is true:
$$P(X > x) \leq P(Y > x).$$

Prove that for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the following is true as well:
$$E[f_a(X)] \leq E[f_a(Y)].$$

I assume that the key part is the fact that $f_a(X)$ and $f_a(Y)$ are both nonnegative random variables. I know that $E(X) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}P(X > n)$ and I've tried solving the problem using these two facts but I couldn't really figure out how to use them.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, forgot about that. I will edit my post immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}Ef_a(X)&=\int_0^{\infty} P(f_a(X) >t)dt\\&=\int_0^{\infty} P(X > a, X>a+t)\\ &\leq \int_0^{\infty} P(Y > a, Y>a+t)\\&=Ef_a(Y)\end{align}

The inequality here follows from the hypothesis since $X>a,X>a+t$ is equivalent to $X>a_t$ and $Y>a,Y>a+t$ is equivalent to $Y>a_t$ where $a_t=\max\{a, a+t\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have two questions - why is $Ef_a(X) = \sum{P(f_a(X) > n)}$? I know this would be true if $f_a(X)$ was a nonnegative integer-valued random variable but this is not the case. Is that equation true for a larger family of random variables?

The second question - I think you wanted to write $\sum{P(Y > a, Y > a + n)}$ in the penultimate step, right?

Comment: @HinkoPihPih You were right on both points. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help!